# Creating an image list based on what is defined as the order, and losing

Tags: php, loops, joomla

I have a custom created module for Joomla 2.5 and within the params of the module, and have a loop that is not outputting as expected. I have the following parameters (fields) int the module:
Order
Thumb image
Image Title
Full-size image

Now there are 10 sets of these group of 4 params. What I am trying to do is loop through each of the object sets, 10 of them, and on each iteration, build an HTML image list structure.

The if statement is building the HTML structure for the sets that have an order value that is greater than 0, and the else is creating the html for those sets that do not have a value greater that 0.

The goal is to create two variables and then concatenate the strings together; the leading sets are the sets that have an order defined. This is not happening and every third loop seems like it is missing.

Here is the order as it is set in the 10 sets

```
Set 1 = 0
Set 2 = 4
Set 3 = 1
Set 4 = 0
Set 5 = 5
Set 6 = 0
Set 7 = 0
Set 8 = 6
Set 9 = 3
Set 10 = 9
```

However, the outcome is:

```
9
5
1
4
6
7
10
```

Instead of the expected:

```
3
9
2
5
8
1 (below here are those sets that were not greater than 0 in order of appearance)
4
6
7
```

What could be wrong here that I can't see?

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $order      = $params->get('order'.$i);#get order for main loop of 10
        $active         = "";
        if ($order > 0) {#Check if greater than 0
            for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {#loop through all order fields looking and build html lowest to highest;
                $ordercheck =$params->get('order'.$n);
                if ($ordercheck == $i) {
                    $img                = $params->get('image'.$n);
                    $fimage         = $params->get('image'.$n.'fullimage');
                    $title          = $params->get('image'.$n.'alttext');
                    $active         = "";
                    $active         = $active . '<li>';
                    $active         = $active .     '<a href="'.$fimage.'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="'.$title.'">';
                    $active         = $active .         '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$title.'" />';
                    $active         = $active .     '</a>';
                    $active         = $active . '</li>';
                    $leading            = $leading . $active;
                }
            }
        } else { #if the itteration $order was not greater than 0, build in order of accourance
            $img                = $params->get('image'.$i);
            $fimage         = $params->get('image'.$i.'fullimage');
            $title          = $params->get('image'.$i.'alttext');
            $active         = $active . '<li>';
            $active         = $active .     '<a href="'.$fimage.'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="'.$title.'">';
            $active         = $active .         '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$title.'" />';
            $active         = $active .         '</a></li>';
            $unordered  = $unordered . $active;
        }
        $imagesList = $leading . $unordered;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you include in your post a vardump of $ordercheck please?

Just from the off though. Isn't if($ordercheck == $i) Going to loop through and output the first, second, 3rd, 4th, 5th image etc. As your just looping that through from 1-10.